# How do I select literal values in an sqlalchemy query?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have a query which looks like this:

```
query = session.query(Item) \
    .filter(Item.company_id == company_id) \
    .order_by(Item.id)
```

It's a pretty basic query. In addition to pulling out the values for the Item, I want to append an additional value into the mix, and have it returned to me. In raw SQL, I would do this:

```
SELECT *, 0 as subscribed
FROM items
WHERE company_id = 34
ORDER BY id
```

How can I manually add that value via sqlalchemy?

Answer (score 104, accepted):

You'll need to use a [`literal_column`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.literal_column), which looks a bit like this:

```
sqlalchemy.orm.Query(Item, sqlalchemy.sql.expression.literal_column("0"))
```

Beware that the `text` argument is inserted into the query without any transformation;  this may expose you to a SQL Injection vulnerability if you accept values for the text parameter from outside your application.  If that's something you need, you'll want to use [`bindparam`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.bindparam), which is about as easy to use; but you will have to invent a name:

```
sqlalchemy.orm.Query(Item, sqlalchemy.sql.expression.bindparam("zero", 0))
```

Comment: Wicked, thanks for that. And just in case anyone finds this question, naming the literal column is done like this:

`literal_column("0").label(col_name)`

Comment: +1 for `bindparam`, its very useful when dealing with string constants.

Comment: I've found that using [`sqlalchemy.sql.expression.literal`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.literal) is a bit more succinct and readable than `bindparam` for string constants.

Comment: Remember, when selecting a literal string, put the value in single quotes. For example, `literal_column("'my_string'")` (at least for Postgres)

Comment: `sqlalchemy.sql.expression.literal` appears to work for other types as well, e.g. an `int`. I noticed it's also available as `sqlalchemy.sql.literal` or `sqlalchemy.literal`, or at least on version 1.1.0b2 it is.

Comment: from sqlalchemy import literal_column

Comment: For anyone who is willing to use string variables for literal_columns value:
literal_column(f"'{location}'").label('location'))

Answer (score 26):

As mentioned in the comments of the accepted answer there's a "shorthand" for [`bindparam()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.bindparam) that alleviates the need to come up with a name for the literal bindparam, [`literal()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.literal):

> Return a literal clause, bound to a bind parameter.

So one does not have to write

```
session.query(Item, bindparam("zero", 0).label("subscribed"))
```

but just

```
session.query(Item, literal(0).label("subscribed"))
```

without having to worry about quoting etc., if passing strings or such.