# How to select virtual column in sqlalchemy?

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

In `mysql`, I could select custom none field from table  static as this:

```
select brand, name, "10" as age from cars
```

How do I do the same for `sqlAlchemy`?

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I select literal values in an sqlalchemy query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7533146/how-do-i-select-literal-values-in-an-sqlalchemy-query)

Comment: Note that (generated) virtual columns have another meaning in MySQL: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-generated-columns.html.

Comment: I did try ‘literal_column()’ seem does not work for me, but ‘literal()’ is just working for this. Thanks for clarify that, @IljaEverilä

Comment: with `literal_column('AmendID').label('AmendID')`, giving a result `ProgrammingError: (ProgrammingError) column "amendid" does not exist`. Actually, I made query of two tables, while those tables having the same columns, first table does not have column `AmendID`. I need to virtually created column `AmendID` for first table; so that I was able to union of both tables. this is i tried to get.

Comment: try `literal('AmendID').label('AmendID')`

Comment: You'll find clarification about `literal_column()` vs. `literal()` in the dupe target and its comments. Look for the paragraph starting with "Beware that the text argument is inserted into the query without any transformation".