# SqlAlchemy adding "string" as a column in results

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

```
candidates = db_session.query(
    Jobs.candidate_id, ## is there a way to eliminate this?
    'Good' ## How do I add this as a column for every person?
    Resumes.resume
).outerjoin(
    (Resumes, Resumes.candidate_id == Jobs.candidate_id),
).outerjoin(
    (Candidate, Candidate.candidate_id == Jobs.candidate_id)
```

Is there a way I can add `Good` as the first column to every result?

Additionally, can I eliminate the `Jobs` category from the `Query` without breaking the `outerjoin`?

Update -

```
can = db_session.query(
    sqlalchemy.sql.expression.literal_column("Good"),
    Jobs.candidate_id
```

I get this error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) no such column: Good
```

I'm using SQLite.

Comment: Adding the string literal: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7533146/how-do-i-select-literal-values-in-an-sqlalchemy-query

Comment: @IljaEverilä still getting an error. I added what I changed

Comment: `literal_column()` puts the string *as is* in to the query, so in that case it's up to you to quote it correctly. If you want to produce an SQL literal from a Python value, use `literal()` instead.

Answer (score 1):

You were very close in your update: use literal_column, but make sure to put the value in single quotes.

In your case:

```
sqlalchemy.sql.expression.literal_column("Good"),
```

Should be:

```
sqlalchemy.sql.expression.literal_column("'Good'"),
```

Your entire query would then look like this:

```
candidates = db_session.query(
    Jobs.candidate_id, ## is there a way to eliminate this?
    sqlalchemy.sql.expression.literal_column("'Good'").label("optional_column_name"),
    Resumes.resume
).outerjoin(
    (Resumes, Resumes.candidate_id == Jobs.candidate_id),
).outerjoin(
    (Candidate, Candidate.candidate_id == Jobs.candidate_id)
```